# Notification cut off

Tags: feature-request, notifications, android-app

Could the android app's notifications that appear in android's notification menu (push notifications I think?) use ... instead of a single dot when the message is cut off?

> I believe it's better to have many small stockpiles. But yo.

That is the notification I got, while the actual answer goes as follows.

> I believe it's better to have many small stockpiles. But you shouldn't put [continues..]

That sends a little different message and opening the site I was expecting a comment or a low quality answer. I thought that was all there was to the post. I would have expected it to say "I believe it's better to have many small stockpiles. But ..." instead to indicate it continues.

Comment: What's the problem, yo?